# Ionic : how to detect bottom scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

For a chat app, I wanted to know if my ion-content is scrolled at bottom, to scroll down again after adding a message only if the user is already at bottom.

It it any possibility to easily detect when the content is scrolled?

Comment: You have provided no code from your application and made no clear attempt at trying to solve it yourself or research the issue. If you hadn't of _immediately_ answered your own question, how did you expect anyone to help when there's nothing to work from? _That_ is why I down voted.

Comment: Yeah, but SO provide a way to answer your own questions, to help the community, and I think the answer is quite self explanatory for anyone who use Ionic... Try asking a new question : don't you see the checkbox at the bottom of the form: *"Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"*?

Comment: Here is what happened: I searched for around half an hour, without finding any solution on SO. When I figured out something, I though it should be good to share it with other. Please don't judge too fast, man.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at `$ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView()`, I found a `__maxScrollTop` property.

The answer is quite simple:

```
var scrollTopCurrent = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;
var scrollTopMax = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().__maxScrollTop;
var scrollBottom = scrollTopMax - scrollTopCurrent;

if (!scrollBottom) {
  $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
}
```

You can even add some tolerance by checking if `scrollBottom` is lower than your tolerance limit.

Comment: You asked and answered your own question literally seconds apart?

Comment: This is why there is a "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" checkbox... To help others because I have to search for half an hour before I find a solution... So why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

we can use **on-scroll** or **on-scroll-complete** events on content then we need to call function in controller like below

```
 $scope.checkScroll = function() {
     var currentTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;
     var maxTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().__maxScrollTop;
     if (currentTop >= maxTop) {
     // hit the bottom

    }
};
```

Complete tutorial is given here http://freakyjolly.com/detect-ionic-view-page-bottom-load-infinite-data/